# How to print pyramid using single loop php?

Tags: php

how to print a pyramid using a single loop with php like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? you have to show as an example of your code, even if it doesn't work yet. stackoverflow is not a platform for contract work: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This is a primitive example solution:

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<6; $i++) {
  echo str_pad('', $i, '*')."\n";
}
```

Another approach is that:

```
<?php
$output = '';
for ($i=1; $i<6; $i++) {
  $output .= '*';
  echo $output."\n";
}
```

The output obviously is:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```